# UITableView Inside UIScrollView scrolling issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my application I want add a tableview inside a `UIScrollView` .When the scroll of  `UITableView` reaches the bounce, it should scroll the outer scrollview. But its not happening for me, `UITableView` is scrolling smoothly.Once it reaches the bounds, it stops.  I need the functionality similar to the attached gif .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please provide some code & you UIScrollView must be smaller than the view.

Comment: what about storyboard how you add scroolview and view heights